# how to display both DisplayName & InstallDate, it's only displaying result for InstallDate

Tags: c#, registry

I would like to read both `DisplayName` and `InstallDate` for uninstall registry, but it only show result for `InstallDate`, how to show result for both?

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Connect();

        string softwareRegLoc = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

        ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("EnumKey");
        inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc;

        // Read Registry Key Names 
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("EnumKey", inParams, null);
        string[] programGuids = outParams["sNames"] as string[];

        foreach (string subKeyName in programGuids)
        {
            inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
            inParams["sSubKeyName"] = softwareRegLoc + @"\" + subKeyName;
            inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";
            inParams["sValueName"] = "InstallDate";
            // Read Registry Value 
            outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
            if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"Value: {outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString()}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you’re associating both to the same key `inParams[“sValueName”]`

Comment: I tried some thing, see my answer. Is this correct or better way?

Answer (score 0):

I got one way but this look code duplication,

```
 inParams["sValueName"] = "DisplayName";
            // Read Registry Value
            outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
            if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"Value: {outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString()}");
            }

            inParams["sValueName"] = "InstallDate";
            // Read Registry Value 
            outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
            if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Value: {outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString()}");
            }
```

Is there other way?